# Convert an for each loop with var inside to a Java Stream?

Tags: java, foreach, java-stream

I have a function:

```
String fun(List<Function<String, String>> pro, String x){

     for(var p: pro){
         x = p.apply(x);
     }
     return x; 
}
```

How can I convert this function to functional style instead of imperative style?

Comment: the list is in a for each loop @khelwood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming what you want is to apply each function to your string, passing along the result of each function to the next, you can do this with [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-).

```java
String fun(List<Function<String, String>> functions, String x) {
    return functions.stream()
                    .reduce(s -> s, Function::andThen)
                    .apply(x);
}
```

Using `reduce` with `andThen` creates a combined function that chains your list of functions together. We then apply the combined function to `x`.

Alternatively, @Naman in the comments suggests the formulation:

```java
functions.stream()
         .reduce(Function::andThen)
         .orElse(Function.identity())
         .apply(x)
```

which I believe performs one fewer `andThen` operation (when the list of functions is nonempty), but is functionally the same as the first version.

([`Function.identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--) is an another way to write `s -> s`.)

Comment: [`andThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-) is a method of `Function` that means "create a function that is the result of doing this function and then another function". `a -> a` is a function that returns its argument unchanged, which is the identity element for the operation of function chaining.

Comment: Id suggest you read the Javadoc, it provides an explanation and example code [Stream#reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator))

Comment: alternatively `functions.stream() .reduce(Function::andThen).orElse(Function.identity).apply(x)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are already aware about those compilation errors. You can't just define `List<Function<>>` without having a common understanding about those list of functions. Maybe you can get some inspiration from below code snippet.

```
String fun(List<Function<String, String>> listOfFunctions, String commonInputStr){
    for (Function<String, String> function : listOfFunctions) {
        String tempValStr = function.apply(commonInputStr);
        if (tempValStr != null){
            return tempValStr;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Or if you want to find the first result value like below:

```
Optional<String> fun(List<Function<String, String>> listOfFunctions, String commonInputStr){

    return listOfFunctions.stream()
            .map(stringStringFunction -> stringStringFunction.apply(commonInputStr))
            .findFirst();
}
```

Comment: yes, I am aware, and I have edited the code. is there a way I can return a String rather than Optional<String>?